# How do I reference a SSRS report parameter in an aggregate function in SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

I have a SSRS report that summarises a dataset from a specified date range.

I'd like to use a report parameter to provide the date range for an aggregate function in the query. Is this even possible?

I have the aggregate function working with variables, but I want to change this so the user can select the date range before the report is run.

Below is the original working aggregate function (in context of the whole query - I've removed the non relevant parts of the query to save confusion).

Notice the @MonthNum and @ReportYear variables being used as criteria for the COUNT() function. I'd like to change these variables to report parameter values, but can't work this out.

```
DECLARE @MonthNum int;
DECLARE @ReportYear int;

SET @MonthNum = CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE())=1) THEN 12 ELSE MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1 END;
SET @ReportYear = CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE())=1) THEN 
YEAR(GETDATE())-1 ELSE YEAR(GETDATE()) END;

SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(tblInvoices.fldDeliveredDate) = @MonthNum AND
(YEAR(tblInvoices.fldDeliveredDate)) = @ReportYear) THEN tblSessions.fldStudioNo END) 
AS MonthVolume

FROM tblInvoices INNER JOIN
tblSessions ON tblInvoices.fldSesID = tblSessions.fldSesID INNER JOIN
tblSessionCustom ON tblSessions.fldSesID = tblSessionCustom.fldSessionCustomID 
INNER JOIN
tblCompInfo ON tblSessions.fldStudioNo = tblCompInfo.fldStudioNo

GROUP BY tblSessions.fldStudioNo, tblCompInfo.fldCompName
HAVING (NOT (tblSessions.fldStudioNo LIKE '999'))
```

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance you can provide. Much appreciated.

Dave

Comment: You need to create the 2 parameters in to the report parameter window for your date and using the Dataset properties window pass that parameters to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need something like the following, you will need to create the parameters @StartDate and @EndDate in SSRS so that they feed into the query:

```
DECLARE @MonthNum int;
DECLARE @ReportYear int,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date

SET @MonthNum = CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE())=1) THEN 12 ELSE MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1 END;
SET @ReportYear = CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE())=1) THEN 
YEAR(GETDATE())-1 ELSE YEAR(GETDATE()) END;

SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(tblInvoices.fldDeliveredDate) = @MonthNum AND
(YEAR(tblInvoices.fldDeliveredDate)) = @ReportYear) THEN tblSessions.fldStudioNo END) 
AS MonthVolume

FROM tblInvoices INNER JOIN
tblSessions ON tblInvoices.fldSesID = tblSessions.fldSesID INNER JOIN
tblSessionCustom ON tblSessions.fldSesID = tblSessionCustom.fldSessionCustomID 
INNER JOIN
tblCompInfo ON tblSessions.fldStudioNo = tblCompInfo.fldStudioNo
Where tblInvoices.fldDeliveredDate between @StartDate and @EndDate

GROUP BY tblSessions.fldStudioNo, tblCompInfo.fldCompName
HAVING (NOT (tblSessions.fldStudioNo LIKE '999'))
```

Comment: Brilliant, that makes a lot of sense mate. Thanks for that I'll give it a run and let you know how I go.

Comment: Thanks again Christian, that solved my issue. Legend! :)

Comment: No Problem @DaveC If you're happy with the answer then you can accept it if you like :)